# preparedStatement and resultSet interfaces how to use batch and get methods

Tags: java, mysql, batch-file, prepared-statement, resultset

I am starting now to use the package java.sql and I am doing some experiments with it.

I have these two tables

the first is:

```
`user` (
`userID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`nickname` VARCHAR(20) NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`userID`) )
```

and the second is:

```
`club` (
`clubID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
'clubName` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
`userID` INT NULL , 
PRIMARY KEY (`clubID`) ,...
```

where userID is a foreign key associated to the userID of the first table.

And this is the code that should explain what I want to do. (this is only for one user-club)

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
this.connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/" + this.database + "?user=" + this.user + "&password=" + this.password);
String s;

s = ("insert into " + this.database + ".user (nickname) values (?)");
this.preparedStatement = this.connect.prepareStatement(s);
this.preparedStatement.setString(1, "username");
this.preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

s = ("SELECT userID from " + this.database + ".user where nickname = 'username'");
this.preparedStatement = this.connect.prepareStatement(s);
this.resultSet = this.preparedStatement.executeQuery();
int n=0;
while (resultSet.next())
{
    n = this.resultSet.getInt("userID");
}

s = ("insert into " + this.database + ".club (clubName, userID) values (?, ?)");
this.preparedStatement = this.connect.prepareStatement(s);
this.preparedStatement.setString(1, "club");
this.preparedStatement.setInt(2, n);
this.preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

If I would do this process for more couples (username, clubname), for example saved in an HashMap how could I use the addBatch() method of preparedStatement Inteface??

I should use three batches one for eache action:
1 insertion of username
2 selection (and recording) of userID
3 insertion of clubname associated to the correct userID

Or I could include all the process in only one batch??

And another question, why If i try to remove the while cycle surrounding the resultSet.getInt() method it gives me an error??

Thanks in advance to all who will try to help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot include all the process in only one batch. The batch is intended for a single query. Here is the [reference link](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/) for a good example.

You can execute multiple queries as different batches as follows .

```
    try {
        DataSource dataSource = null;// specify data source
        Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
        Statement s = con.createStatement();
        // or
        // PreparedStatement s =
        // con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO profile (fullname) VALUES ('Visruth CV')");
        s.addBatch("INSERT INTO tran1 (username, password, profileid) VALUES ('visruth', 'password', 1)");
        s.addBatch("INSERT INTO testtab (name) VALUES ('testtab')");
        s.executeBatch();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If you remove the `while (resultSet.next())` loop, it will make a *NullPointerException* because the current position of the cursor in the `resultSet` is in the default row, when you make `resultSet.next()` the cursor will jump in to the next row if there is a row available (from the default row to first row, first row to second row etc...) and at the same time `resultSet.next()` will return true (only if it jumps) otherwise false. If `resultSet` contains more than one row, it can be put inside a *while loop*, if not just need to use the *if condition* there.